# Bell's inequality

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables

Let $\xi, \eta, \zeta$ be random variables such that $|\xi|, |\eta|, |\zeta| \le 1$. I need to prove such inequality:

$|\mathbb{E}(\zeta \xi)-\mathbb{E}(\zeta \eta)| \le 1 - \mathbb{E}(\xi \eta)$

Even with assumption that $\zeta, \xi, \eta$ are independent, I failed with it. I've even tried to prove

$(\mathbb{E}( \xi)-\mathbb{E}( \eta))^2 \le (1 - \mathbb{E}(\xi \eta))^2$

with help of estimation:

$(\mathbb{E}(\xi-\eta))^2 \le (\mathbb{E}(\xi-\eta)^2) = 2 - 2\mathbb{E}(\xi \eta)$

but

$2 - 2\mathbb{E}(\xi \eta) \ge (1 - \mathbb{E}(\xi \eta))^2$.

Does anybody know how to prove the statement?

Comment: What is this $E$?

Comment: @ellya, this is Expected value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume that $x$, $y$ and $z$ are all in $[-1,1]$, then 
$$(1-x)(1+y)\geqslant0,\qquad(1+x)(1-y)\geqslant0,$$ hence $$x-y\leqslant1-xy,\qquad y-x\leqslant1-xy.$$ Since $|x-y|=\max\{x-y,y-x\}$, this implies that $|x-y|\leqslant1-xy$.
Since $|z|\leqslant1$,
$$
|zx-zy|=|z|\cdot|x-y|\leqslant|x-y|\leqslant1-xy.
$$
Replacing $(x,y,z)$ by $(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$, one gets the pointwise inequality 
$$|\zeta\xi-\zeta\eta|\leqslant1-\xi\eta.
$$
Integrating this inequality yields 
$$|E(\zeta\xi)-E(\zeta\eta)|\leqslant E(|\zeta\xi-\zeta\eta|)\leqslant1-E(\xi\eta),
$$
as desired.

Comment: @saz Sorry... :-)